# How to quickly find constructor(s) in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there way to quickly find constructors of a particular class in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: I want to do this all the time!  But sadly, if the two answers here are all we have, then we really don't have a solution (the given answers provide way more info than just the constructors, sigh).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>. This will show all members of the current class in a popup window, then you can select the constructor easily.

Command + F12 on Mac

Comment: I love IntelliJ, but in this matter Eclipse makes a better job, as it displays a C icon for constructors.

Comment: cmd + F12 on Mac. Works in PhpStorm (typescript) too

Comment: Yes, CLion needs to improve on providing C++ type info. It is missing several aspects that IntelliJ has for Java. There is a whole bunch of related feature requests here you can vote up - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-2884.

Comment: constructor display on top of the popup list.

Answer (score 17):

I generally use the "Parameter Info" Keymap to show all options for a constructor.

If you type out the initial skeleton (new ConstructorClass()) and place the cursor in the brackets, the Parameter Info command will show all possible parameters for all overloaded constructors. This also works for overloaded methods.

N.B. My IntelliJ settings have Ctrl+p as the keymap for "Parameter Info". You will have to check your settings for your mapping.

Comment: Note: To see parameter of a constructor, need to **place the cursor in the brackets**, then Crtl+P